# Add a column to dataframe based on values from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, match, data-science

I have a dataframe `test` with 1 column `exposure`

```
    exposure                       
1    CD177 
2    RFESD 
3    IL12B                       
4   IL18R1 
5      CEL
```

I want to add a column to `test` based on the columns `count_type` from another dataframe `test1` below

```
  Exposure cis.trans count_type
 1:    CD177       cis          1
 2:    CD177       cis          1
 3:    CD177       cis          1
 4:    CD177       cis          1
 5:    CD177       cis          1
 6:    CD177       cis          1
 7:    CD177       cis          1
 8:      CEL       cis          1
 9:    IL12B     trans          2
10:    IL12B       cis          2
11:   IL18R1       cis          1
12:   IL18R1       cis          1
13:   IL18R1       cis          1
14:    RFESD       cis          1
```

`if count_type  =1` I want to take the value from `cis.trans` column otherwise the value will be `"mix"`
In this example I want to get this :

```
 exposure  typ
1    CD177 cis 
2    RFESD cis 
3    IL12B mix
4   IL18R1 cis
5      CEL cis
```

Here is my code:

```
test<-test%>%
  mutate( typ=ifelse(test1[match(test$exposure,test1$Exposure),"count_type"]==1,
                     test1[match(test$exposure,test1$Exposure),"cis.trans"],
                     "mix"))
```

What I am getting is the following:

```
exposure                       typ
1    CD177 cis, cis, trans, cis, cis
2    RFESD cis, cis, trans, cis, cis
3    IL12B                       mix
4   IL18R1 cis, cis, trans, cis, cis
5      CEL cis, cis, trans, cis, cis
```

I don't know where is the problem I tried the following to test what match is returning and it is indeed returning the index of the wanted value from the test1 dataframe

```
test<-test%>%
  mutate( typ_ind=ifelse(test1[match(test$exposure,test1$Exposure),"count_type"]==1,
                     match(test$exposure,test1$Exposure),
                     "mix"))

test
  exposure                       typ count_type
1    CD177 cis, cis, trans, cis, cis          1
2    RFESD cis, cis, trans, cis, cis         14
3    IL12B                       mix        mix
4   IL18R1 cis, cis, trans, cis, cis         11
5      CEL cis, cis, trans, cis, cis          8
```

**Any idea on what's happening and how to fix it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only unique rows for `test1` based on `Exposure` and `count_type` column and join the data with `test`. Change the value of `cis.trans` to `"mix"` if `count_type = 2`.

```
library(dplyr)

test1 %>%
  distinct(Exposure, count_type, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  inner_join(test, by = c('Exposure' = 'exposure')) %>%
  mutate(cis.trans  = ifelse(count_type == 2, 'mix', cis.trans))

#  Exposure cis.trans count_type
#1    CD177       cis          1
#2      CEL       cis          1
#3    IL12B       mix          2
#4   IL18R1       cis          1
#5    RFESD       cis          1
```

Comment: Thanks the answer worked for this case but the names are taken from test1 dataframe I need the names to stay same as test because in fact the dataframes have much more columns than this example. When I apply the code to my data all columns from test1 are added to test

Comment: I did select manually the columns I wanted to keep and changed the name with `select` and `rename`

Comment: You can change the order of join and use `select` to keep the columns you need in the final dataframe. `test %>%inner_join(test1 %>% distinct(Exposure, count_type, .keep_all = TRUE), by = c('exposure' = 'Exposure')) %>% select(col1, col2) %>%
  mutate(cis.trans  = ifelse(count_type == 2, 'mix', cis.trans))` . Replace `col1`, `col2` with actual column names in your data.